# Setting different font and colors for distraction free editing in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2

Sublime Text 2 comes with distraction free editing mode which uses full screen layout. The full screen layout leaves room for using different styles for different purposes... e.g. for typing on your computer on sunlight using high contrast font with larger pixel site.

Does Sublime Text 2 offer ways to customize the colors and fonts just for the distraction free editing mode?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can edit Distraction Free settings going to: Preferences > Settings - More > Distraction Free - User. The default settings are:

```
{
    "line_numbers": false,
    "gutter": false,
    "draw_centered": true,
    "wrap_width": 80,
    "word_wrap": true,
    "scroll_past_end": true
}
```

You can add "color_scheme" and "font_face". Just like that:

```
{
    "line_numbers": false,
    "gutter": false,
    "draw_centered": true,
    "wrap_width": 80,
    "word_wrap": true,
    "scroll_past_end": true,
    "color_scheme": "Packages/Theme - Aqua/Color Schemes/Espresso Aqua.tmTheme",
    "font_face": "Bitstream Vera Sans Mono"
}
```